# Im getting a RSA bad padding exception

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I cannot seem to find a awnser to why my program wont work
I have already checked the keys and they are the same
here is my error

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error null at
>   sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380) at
>   sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291) at
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363) at
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389) at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165) at
>   com.thatmadhacker.finlaybot.client.FinlayBot.rsadecrypt(FinlayBot.java:234)
>   at
>   com.thatmadhacker.finlaybot.client.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:16)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

here is mv key generator code

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = null;
    try {


        kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
        publicKey = kp.getPublic();
        privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        pub = fact.getKeySpec(kp.getPublic(),
          RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
        priv = fact.getKeySpec(kp.getPrivate(),
          RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

        saveToFile("public.key", pub.getModulus(),
          pub.getPublicExponent());
        saveToFile("private.key", priv.getModulus(),
          priv.getPrivateExponent());

    } catch (Exception e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here are my decryption and encryption methods

```
public static String rsadecrypt(byte[] text) {
try {
// get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

// decrypt the text using the private key
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text);
return new String(dectyptedText);
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
public static byte[] rsaencrypt(String text) {

try {
  // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
  final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
  // encrypt the plain text using the public key
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, clientKey);
  byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
  return cipherText;
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
```

and then here is my server thread that performing a key exchange

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        java.io.PrintWriter unEncryptOut = new java.io.PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        unEncryptOut.println(FinlayBot.pub.getModulus());
        unEncryptOut.println(FinlayBot.pub.getPublicExponent());
        unEncryptOut.flush();
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(in.nextLine());
        BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(in.nextLine());
        RSAPublicKeySpec pub = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus,exponent);
        try {
            FinlayBot.clientKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(pub);
            //System.out.println(modulus +"             "+exponent);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and the client

```
System.out.println("Waiting For KeyPair!");
pubKeyModulus = new BigInteger(in.nextLine().trim());
pubKeyExponent = new BigInteger(in.nextLine().trim());
//System.out.println(pubKeyModulus+"      "+pubKeyExponent);
System.out.println("Recieved KeyPair!");


RSAPublicKeySpec pub = new RSAPublicKeySpec(pubKeyModulus, pubKeyExponent);
try {

    serverPublicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(pub);
    System.out.println(pub.getModulus()+"      "+pub.getPublicExponent());
    writer.println(pub.getModulus());
    writer.println(pub.getPublicExponent());
    writer.flush();
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The error is likely in the code you haven't shown us, the code the calls the encrypt/decrypt routines and outputs/inputs the ciphertext.

Comment: the other code is like 10 lines of code that read and write from the data streams and that send 2 big integers between eachother for a key exchange